# Why is the below code giving me "adviceDidNotMatch"

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am trying to learn `AspectJ` and so far I am getting used to the concepts well. So here I am trying to write the aspect class for validation on an Object. But the below code gives me `adviceDidNotMatch` thing.

```
before(com.message.pojo.Entity entity) : call(*public com.message.helper.Processor.process(com.message.pojo.Entity))
     && args(entity)
        && target(com.message.helper.MessageProcessor){
        ValidationUtil validation = new ValidationUtil();
        validation.validate(entity);
    }
```

Now all the qualified names here I check is correct. Please check the screenshot of my java project structure.

[[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a little syntax problem in your pointcut: Instead of `call(* public` it should be `call(public *`, then it works.

BTW, you can also replace your fully qualified class names by imports in native AspectJ syntax. The FQDN are only necessary in annotation-based @AspectJ syntax. Assuming that we are talking about `ValidationAspect` from your screenshot, for the two classes in the same package you do not even need any imports. Try it like this:

```java
package com.message.helper;

import com.message.pojo.Entity;

public aspect ValidationAspect {
  before(Entity entity) :
    call(public * Processor.process(Entity)) &&
    args(entity) &&
    target(MessageProcessor)
  {
    ValidationUtil validation = new ValidationUtil();
    validation.validate(entity);
  }
}
```